# How to find wmsURL? And how to use QueryTask method?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms, rest

I have couple of questions.

1. var wmsLayer = new esri.layers.WMSLayer(wmsURL); with this line of code i can display wms layer over any base Layer. Now From where I get wmsURL ? I have published my shapefile on GeoServer, but i dont know how i get the URL (wmsURL) to use as parameter in above line of code ?
2. Now, Let's suppose I am successful to display wmsLayer. Now i want to query data against this wmsLayer. Like code below:

queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("wmsURL"); Can I use wmsURL as a parameter in QueryTask method ? From ArcGIS API reference, I come to know that the URL parameter of QueryTask method is the URL to the ArcGIS Server REST resource. But as u know i am using GeoServer, so how it could be fixed. Need some explanation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would normally be something like http://mydomain.com/ArcGIS/services/mylayerservicename/MapServer/WMSServer
where you supply the domain and servicename.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the documentation for esri.layers.WMSLayer to see what sort of URL it requires. It might be a getcapabilities request so something like http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities or may be it is a complete getmap request http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver/wms?LAYERS=topp%3Astates&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=-139.84813671875,18.549615234375,-51.85286328125,55.778384765625&WIDTH=780&HEIGHT=330 or may be it is some subset of this (i.e. the program can fill in the sizes or format)?

Answer (score 2):

Q1. The wmsURL would probably be something like http://www.myserver.com/geoserver203/wms

Q2. It's not possible to use the QueryTask to query a geoserver.